# Find the function $f(x)$ from the primitive function $F(x)=\cos^4(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

This is what I've done so far. The answer should be $f(x)=-0.5(\sin 4x-\sin 2x))$

\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\cos^4(x)
\\ F’(x)&=-4(\cos^3(x))\sin x
\\&= -4(\cos^2(x))\cos x\sin x
\\&=- 4(1-\sin^2(x))\cos x\sin x
\\&=- 2\cdot 2(1-\sin^2(x))\cos x\sin x
\\&= -2(1-\sin^2(x))\sin 2x
\\&= (-2+2\sin^2(x))\sin 2x
\\&=-2\sin 2x+2\sin^2(x)\sin 2x
\end{align*}

Now I'm kind of stuck

Thank you guys for editing the equations. This is what i have calculated with your help:

-2sin2x+(1-cos2x)*sin2x

-2sin2x+sin2x-(cos2x*sin2x)

-sin2x- (cos2x*sin2x)    (multiply by 2)

-2sin2x-2cos2x*sin2x

-2sin2x-sin4x  (now divide by 4)

-0,5(sin2x+sin4x)

still I feel like it is wrong

Comment: @user376343  No, he means $\cos^4 x$.

Comment: Now write $2\sin^2x$ as $1-\cos2x$

Comment: Thank you guys for editing the equations. This is what i have calculated with your help: 
-2sin2x+(1-cos2x)*sin2x
-2sin2x+sin2x-(cos2x*sin2x)
-sin2x- (cos2x*sin2x)    (multiply by 2)
-2sin2x-2cos2x*sin2x
-2sin2x-sin4x  (now divide by 4)
-0,5(sin2x+sin4x)

still I feel that it is wrong

Comment: $f(x)=-0.5\sin(4x)-\sin(2x)\neq -0.5(\sin(4x)-\sin(2x))$

Comment: Could it be that the derivative of  F(x) is −0.5sin(4x)−sin(2x) and not −0.5(sin(4x)−sin(2x))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result of $F'(x)=4\cos^3x\sin x$ actually happens to be just fine. Integrating to go from $f(x)$ to $F(x)$ shows that your solution is perfectly acceptable. Unless your class asks such of you, I would certainly not go through the work to reduce the powers.

Comment: I think the two  last steps are wrong. Dividing by 4 would result in -0,5sin2x-0,25sin4x. Or?

Comment: Using an integration technique called u-substitution (or change of variables), you end up integrating u^4/4, and that constant 4 hanging out there cancels out with the 1/4, thus leaving us with u^4=cos^4(x).